# When should one use a 'www' subdomain?

Tags: subdomain

When browsing through the internet for the last few years, I'm seeing more and more pages getting rid of the 'www' subdomain.

Are there any good reasons to use or not to use the 'www' subdomain?

Comment: Nobody has mentioned the fact that firefox (and I think IE, maybe others) automatically adds the www. and .com if you type, say, "stackoverflow" in the address bar and press ctrl-enter. One more little reason to at least handle the www, even if you redirect it to the bare domain.

Comment: @bstpierre - i use this constantly, funny how i don't see it mentioned very much

Comment: @bias: Have you tried the feature? From your comment, it doesn't sound like you have. It saves a couple of keystrokes -- you don't have to type the ".com". As boomhauer mentioned, it's something people may be using frequently, and it's built-in to the browsers, so it's a reason to handle "www.", even if you just redirect it. I.e. in your browser, type Ctrl-T (for a new tab), "stackoverflow", Ctrl-Enter, you will navigate to "www.stackoverflow.com", and you will then be redirected to "stackoverflow.com". (Similarly, Ctrl-Shift-Enter goes to .org and Shift-Enter goes to .net, at least in FF3.)

Comment: @bstpierre I use vimperator, so I don't interact with the navigation bar but when I do I just press <Enter>. Also, my point is that I think most users press <Enter> as opposed to more complex chorded sequences when using firefox. I really am worried that changing DNS based on arbitrary idiosyncrasies is a horrible idea and will hurt the user.

Comment: See also on Webmasters: [WWW.yoursite.com or HTTP://yoursite.com which one is futureproof?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/6107/17633)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

There are a ton of good reasons to include it, the best of which is here:
[Yahoo Performance Best Practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free)

Due to the dot rule with cookies, if you don't have the 'www.' then you can't set two-dot cookies or cross-subdomain cookies a la *.example.com. There are two pertinent impacts.

First it means that any user you're giving cookies to will send those cookies back with requests that match the domain. So even if you have a subdomain, images.example.com, the example.com cookie will always be sent with requests to that domain. This creates overhead that wouldn't exist if you had made [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) the authoritative name. Of course you can use a CDN, but that depends on your resources.

Also, you then don't have the ability to set a cross-subdomain cookie. This seems evident, but this means allowing authenticated users to move between your subdomains is more of a technical challenge.

So ask yourself some questions. Do I set cookies? Do I care about potentially needless bandwidth expenditure? Will authenticated users be crossing subdomains? If you're really concerned with inconveniencing the user, you can always configure your server to take care of the www/no www thing automatically.

See [dropwww](https://dropwww.com/why) and [yes-www](https://www.yes-www.org/) ([saved](https://web.archive.org/web/20220326054917/https://www.yes-www.org/)).

Comment: I know it's an old post, but yes-www doesn't seem to work now.

Answer (score 46):

Just after asking this question I came over the [no-www](http://no-www.org/) page which says:

> ...Succinctly, use of the www subdomain
>   is redundant and time consuming to
>   communicate. The internet, media, and
>   society are all better off without it.

Comment: When [the inventor of the World Wide Web wishes he'd dropped the two forward slashes](https://tech.slashdot.org/story/09/10/14/1219215/tim-berners-lee-is-sorry-about-the-slashes) to save paper and human labour, it's clear we should drop `www.` wherever possible.

Answer (score 34):

Take it from a domainer, Use both the www.domainname.com and the normal domainname.com
otherwise you are just throwing your traffic away to the browers search engine (DNS Error)

Actually it is amazing how many domains out there, especially amongst the top 100, correctly resolve for www.domainname.com but not domainname.com

Comment: You should choose one to be canonical http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/

Answer (score 13):

There are MANY reasons to use the www sub-domain!

When writing a URL, it's easier to handwrite and type "www.stackoverflow.com", rather than "http://stackoverflow.com". Most text editors, email clients, word processors and WYSIWYG controls will automatically recognise both of the above and create hyperlinks. Typing just "stackoverflow.com" will not result in a hyperlink, after all it's just a domain name.. Who says there's a web service there? Who says the reference to that domain is a reference to its web service?

What would you rather write/type/say.. "www." (4 chars) or "http://" (7 chars) ??

"www." is an established shorthand way of unambiguously communicating the fact that the subject is a web address, not a URL for another network service.

When verbally communicating a web address, it should be clear from the context that it's a web address so saying "www" is redundant. Servers should be configured to return HTTP 301 (Moved Permanently) responses forwarding all requests for @.stackoverflow.com (the root of the domain) to the www subdomain.

In my experience, people who think WWW should be omitted tend to be people who don't understand the difference between the web and the internet and use the terms interchangeably, like they're synonymous. The web is just one of many network services.

If you want to get rid of www, why not change the your HTTP server to use a different port as well, TCP port 80 is sooo yesterday.. Let's change that to port 1234, YAY now people have to say and type "http://stackoverflow.com:1234" (eightch tee tee pee colon slash slash stack overflow dot com colon one two three four) but at least we don't have to say "www" eh?

Comment: You can still use `www.example.com` (for "www." being shorter than "http://"), but then redirect to "example.com".
You should listen to both, but what you're using as the canonical one does not really matter (apart from cookie/subdomain issues mentioned by jdangel)

Comment: Those arguments are ridiculous. Saying `www.` doesn't guarentee that someone will actually access it via HTTP over port 80, you just assume they will. Likewise, if you say to someone "stackoverflow.com" they will access it the same way. HTTP is a W3C standard protocol, browsers will add the `http://` because they *need* a protocol and just assume HTTP if it's missing. `http://www.` is not shorter than `http://`. Cookies are the *only* valid reasion to use `www.`, and even then that's only if you're too cheap to get a CDN or a second domain.

Comment: What? This is poor reasoning. "www." is a waste of everyone's time. If your e-mail program does not change regular domains into hyperlinks (1) make the hyperlinks manually or (2) get a new e-mail client.

Comment: Actually, saying "www." may be only 4 chars but it is 10 syllables - longer than "http://"'s 7 syllables. More syllable irony: saying the "shortened" www is 3 times longer than just saying "world wide web"

Comment: Using "www." at the beginning of a link doesn't make it absolute, it will be relative (see http://jsfiddle.net/FQTSE/). And you say "www." is shorter that "http://", and it's true, but in most cases you can just use "//", which is even shorter and makes the url absolute.

Comment: @Kristian B. `now people have to say and type "http://stackoverflow.com:1234" `. Yes, but who can't love `"http://slashdot.org"` (haych tee tee pee colon slash slash slash dot dot org_"?

Comment: You said "people who think WWW should be omitted tend to be people who don't understand the difference between the web and the internet". Do you really understand the difference?
The main thing which differ a page from a mailbox is a protocol that you have to specify when you use a domain. But browsers do that for you and add "http" in the beginning of the address you type.
www.abc.com and abc.com are different domains but neither the first nor the second one don't say which protocol should be used and in both cases it could be http/pop/smtp/ftp/rsync/mysql or whatever you want.

Answer (score 13):

There are several reasons, here are some:

**1) The person wanted it this way on purpose**

People use DNS for many things, not only the web.   They may need the main dns name for some other service that is more important to them.

**2) Misconfigured dns servers**

If someone does a lookup of www to your dns server, your DNS server would need to resolve it.

**3) Misconfigured web servers**

A web server can host many different web sites.  It distinguishes which site you want via the Host header.  You need to specify which host names you want to be used for your website.

**4) Website optimization**

It is better to not handle both, but to forward one with a moved permanently http status code.  That way the 2 addresses won't compete for inbound link ranks.

**5) Cookies**

To avoid problems with cookies not being sent back by the browser.  This can also be solved with the moved permanently http status code.

**6) Client side browser caching**

Web browsers may not cache an image if you make a request to www and another without.  This can also be solved with the moved permanently http status code.

Answer (score 11):

There is no huge advantage to including-it or not-including-it and no one objectively-best strategy. “no-www.org” is a silly load of old dogma trying to present itself as definitive fact.

If the “big organisation that has many different services and doesn't want to have to dedicate the bare domain name to being a web server” scenario doesn't apply to you (and in reality it rarely does), which address you choose is a largely cultural matter. Are people where you are used to seeing a bare “example.org” domain written on advertising materials, would they immediately recognise it as a web address without the extra ‘www’ or ‘http://’? In Japan, for example, you would get funny looks for choosing the non-www version.

Whichever you choose, though, be consistent. Make both www and non-www versions accessible, but make *one* of them definitive, always link to that version, and make the other redirect to it (permanently, status code 301). Having both hostnames respond directly is bad for SEO, and serving *any old* hostname that resolves to your server leaves you open to DNS rebinding attacks.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from the load optimization regarding cookies, there is also a DNS related reason for using the `www` subdomain. You can't use **CNAME** to the naked domain. On [yes-www.org](http://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/) ([saved](https://web.archive.org/web/20220318161008/http://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/)) it says:

> When using a provider such as **Heroku** or **Akamai** to host your web site, the provider wants to be able to update DNS records in case it needs to redirect traffic from a failing server to a healthy server. This is set up using DNS **CNAME** records, and the naked domain cannot have a CNAME record. 
>  This is only an issue if your site gets large enough to require highly redundant hosting with such a service.

Answer (score 6):

As jdangel points out the www is good practice in some cookie situations but I believe there is another reason to use www.

Isn't it our responsibility to care for and protect our users. As most people expect www, you will give them a less than perfect experience by not programming for it.

To me it seems a little arrogant, to not set up a DNS entry just because in theory it's not required. There is no overhead in carrying the DNS entry and through redirects etc they can be redirected to a non www dns address.

Seriously don't loose valuable traffic by leaving your potential visitor with an unnecessary "site not found" error.

Additionally in a windows only network you might be able to set up a windows DNS server to avoid the following problem, but I don't think you can in a mixed environment of mac and windows. If a mac does a DNS query against a windows DNS mydomain.com will return all the available name servers not the webserver. So if in your browser you type mydomain.com you will have your browser query a name server not a webserver, in this case you need a subdomain (eg www.mydomain.com ) to point to the specific webserver.

Answer (score 3):

Some sites require it because the service is configured on that particular set up to deliver web content via the www sub-domain only.

This is correct as www is the conventional sub-domain for "World Wide Web" traffic. 
Just as port 80 is the standard port. Obviously there are other standard services and ports as well (http tcp/ip on port 80 is nothing special!)

Imagine mycompany...

mx1.mycompany.com 25 smtp, etc

ftp.mycompany.com 21 ftp

www.mycompany.com 80 http

Sites that don't require it basically have forwarding in dns or redirection of some-kind.

e.g.

*.mycompany.com 80 http

The onlty reason to do it as far as I can see is if you prefer it and you want to.

Comment: Looking at your example, I think I should have www.

Answer (score 0):

I say ALWAYS use www because it allows you to easier upscale when needed because you can use ww2 or my favorite backup subdomain, wwv because it looks almost like www so most users will just not look at it. the ability to upscale with more servers is very useful. I can have 4 backup servers with the subdomains wwv wwu wwww wwwv

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).