# Cannot use Network Admin (Dashboard) on Multi-site after 301 www redirect

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

I have recently added the 301 redirect non-WWW to WWW on .htaccess for my current running blog multisite (Wordpress blog resides under "mysite.com/home/" directory), they seem to work fine after all the changes in those 3 files below:

**.HTACCESS**

```
# Redirect Non-WWW to WWW
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com\home
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/home/$1 [R=301,L]
# END Redirect Non-WWW to WWW

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /home/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**WP-CONFIG.PHP**

Change From

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mysite.com');
```

Change To

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.mysite.com');
```

**FUNCTIONS.PHP (OF THE MAIN THEME)**

Change From

```
update_option('siteurl','http://mysite.com/home');
update_option('home','http://mysite.com/home');
global $oswcPostTypes;
```

Change To

```
update_option('siteurl','http://www.mysite.com/home');
update_option('home','http://www.mysite.com/home');
global $oswcPostTypes;
```

I could be able to view my sites as usual and log-in to each Site Dashboard **BUT CANNOT BE ABLE TO USE the network tab:** My Sites > Network Admin > Dashboard, Sites, Users. Is there anywhere else needed to change in order to be able to use the network tab on multisite without using any plugin or changes all the data in the database?

Comment: Why not redir from www to the TLD? http://no-www.org/ More discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486621/when-should-one-use-a-www-subdomain

Comment: I am doing the opposite, no-www to with-www.

Answer (score 3):

Your redirect seems to have a bad condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com\home
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/home/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `%{HTTP_HOST}` is what's in the "Host:" header request and it only contains a hostname (and sometimes a port), you can't have URI paths in there. Try changing it to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com
RewriteRule ^/?home/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/home/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

your value "$current_blog->domain, $current_site->domain" must be same with "$current_blog->path, $current_site->path" in /wp-admin/network/admin.php line 20.

Check your *_wp_blogs table in domain and path column.

Update your domain value from mysite.com to www.mysite.com