# The difference between http://example.com and http://www.example.com

Tags: http

When I was doing some web design, I found one interesting thing.

When I type

> http://example.com/xxx/xxx

it always asks me for credentials. However, when I use

> http://www.example.com/xxx/xxx

it logs me in directly! I know there is something with the cookie.

But what I really want to know is:

**What is the difference between `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com`?**

Do tell me it is the browser automatically adding "`www`" to the url.

Thanks, 
: )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

www is a [subdomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain) like any other (e.g. [http://**math**.stackexchange.com/](http://math.stackexchange.com)). It's just a convention to have it point to the same place as the main domain. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/486763/622391) has some good points about *why* you would use www.