# Is www a subdomain?

Tags: dns

I recently purchased `something.com`.

When I visit `something.com` from my browser, I get the index page I uploaded on server.
However, if I visit `www.something.com`, it shows Error 404.

So I create a sub-domain named 'www' and upload another index file there.

Now, `www.something.com` and `something.com` shows two different websites.

My question is, is 'www' a normal sub-domain? Or some special kind of sub-domain? If yes, how is it different from other sub-domains?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486621/when-should-one-use-a-www-subdomain

Comment: Also: [What’s the point in having “www” in a URL?](http://serverfault.com/questions/145777/whats-the-point-in-having-www-in-a-url)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

*is 'www' a normal sub-domain?* Yes, it is. From the point of view of DNSs it is a totally normal subdomain.

*is some special kind of sub-domain?* Yes, it is, indeed. It is so commonly used that most Registrars and Hosting providers do automatically create it for you and permanently redirect it to the web server hosted with them.

in your case, it seems that this is not what happens. So, create it and permanently redirect it, instead of creating a new index page for it.