# Github pages Error "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" when entering website via https://www

Tags: html, https, dns, github-pages, insecure-connection

**When entering my website via url prefix https://www I get error "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID".**
Via prefix www & https:// & without a prefix the website loads fine (I get no error).

I tried setting up a permanent redirect as suggestion in first answer here [GitHub Pages https/www Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54817253/github-pages-https-www-redirect) in google domains settings, however this overwrites my A record for github pages... and when i try to reconfigure this a-record after setting up the redirect the redirect is removed automatically by google domains.

I also tried the accepted answer from the same post. Unfortunately this gave me a **'invalid dns' error** when doing dns check on github pages after setting custom domain back to troosbouw.com

**I tried multiple machines, browsers and networks with same results.**
I suspect its an issue with DNS settings but if so i dont know what i did wrong in my settings.
**Any input/hints as to what might be the issue are greatly appreciated!**

**DNS Settings:**
[image: DNS Settings]

**Error:**
[image]

**Github pages https:**
I'm hosting via Github pages, i have 'enforce https' enabled in pages settings.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the same IP addresses on the `www` subdomain.
And use `www` in **Settings/Custom domain**.